# Why can't GWT deserialize the native datastore key any more?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, deserialization, objectify, gwt-2.5

I've only started to have this problem having upgraded all of my libraries:

I was using GWT 2.4, App Engine 1.6.3 and Objectify 3.0.

I upgraded to GWT 2.5, App Engine 1.7.4 and Objectify 4.0b1.

Since then I am getting this strange error that [only 1 other person](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/objectify-appengine/MYqkp4YiBBY/discussion) seems to have on the entire internet!

Stack trace:

```java
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key/1349195865
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.Key_FieldSerializer.deserialize(Key_FieldSerializer.java:11)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.Key_FieldSerializer.deserial(Key_FieldSerializer.java:29)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.deserialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.deserialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_FieldSerializer.deserial(ArrayList_FieldSerializer.java:19)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.utilitiessavings.testapp2.shared.Account_FieldSerializer.deserialize(Account_FieldSerializer.java:29)
    at com.utilitiessavings.testapp2.shared.Account_FieldSerializer.deserial(Account_FieldSerializer.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.deserialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.deserialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_FieldSerializer.deserial(ArrayList_FieldSerializer.java:19)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.utilitiessavings.testapp2.client.action.GetAccountsResult_FieldSerializer.deserialize(GetAccountsResult_FieldSerializer.java:20)
    at com.utilitiessavings.testapp2.client.action.GetAccountsResult_FieldSerializer.deserial(GetAccountsResult_FieldSerializer.java:38)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
    ... 27 more
```

The problem is occuring when deserializing Account as it contains an Objectify [Key](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html) which wraps the native [datastore key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key).

Serializing works fine, and my object graph is all fine and dandy in the datastore, I just can't get anything back that contains a Key, which is pretty much everything useful.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Project clean and ensure there is nothing from cache or old generated files that are left behind. Restart, relaunch and try again. Sometimes its just cached values.

Comment: Have tried deleting everything in the gwt-unitCache folder, and cleaning. Nothing seems to work. Serialization policy maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue and it seems that it has nothing to do with the datastore either because when I sent an object to the server and tried to retrieve it back I still got a deserialization error.

```
AsyncCallService{

void createUser(User user, AsyncCallback<User> user);
}

ServiceImpl{

User createUser(User user){

DB.save(user);

return user

}
```

And this is still causing Serialization errors  or rather deserializaton errors on the client.

What I've done was just pass back a new User;

```
User createUser(User user){
DB.save(user);
User newUser = new User();

newUser.setId(user.getId())

return newUser;
```

}

Problem solved except that now I've lost some of the "benefits" of older app engine stack where deserialization wasn't necessary.